# How can I put the students to their own class with their perspective class and teacher using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

So basically I'm studying mysql how can I put the student to their own class

Example 1810932 Al Jake ,his teacher would be Cris Greeg which the student will attend an english class
1810933 Alisson Zach ,his teacher would be Paul Jake which the student will attend to an
mathematics and also Cris Greeg has a student named Al Jake and Paul Jake has a student named Alisson Zac

here is the code that I did but I cant get the exact result

```
select en.*
   ,sc.teacher
   ,sc.day
   ,sc.tstart
   ,sc.tend
   ,sc.descc
   ,sc.sem
   ,sc.room
   ,sc.school_year
from enrollment en 
inner join schedule sc 
    on sc.year = en.year
```

[image: table : enrollment]

[image: table : schedule]

[image: EXPECTED OUTPUT]

Comment: your question is not clear , how do you specify that each student participated in which class?

Comment: @eshirvana sorry sir for my bad explanation, It worked now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing one condition in `join`. Use following query:

```
select en.*
   ,sc.teacher
   ,sc.day
   ,sc.tstart
   ,sc.tend
   ,sc.descc
   ,sc.sem
   ,sc.room
   ,sc.school_year
from enrollment en 
inner join schedule sc 
    on sc.year = en.year
   And sc.section = en.section -- added this condition
```

Comment: thank you so much sir god bless I just missed out a little haha thanks once again